# Error checking in Eclipse for a single file

Tags: java, eclipse, netbeans

I am using Eclipse to modify a single .java file and then compiling it externally. With Netbeans it was possible to have error checking, such as syntax errors, even if the file is nor part of any project. Is it possible to do the same in Eclipse?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No. Eclipse needs the context of a project in order to parse and process code. Without that context, it has no way of knowing what JDK compliance level, library, etc the code is supposed to compile against.